# Webpack-2 to load module A before loading module B?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, es6-modules

I have package B from `npm` which basically does this.

```
   (function(M) { if(M.jQuery) { /* do stuff */ } })(window);
```

I can't use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` because its not directly using `jQuery`.

So i create `A.js` which does this.

```
   import $ from 'jquery';
   window.jQuery = $;
```

[It seems](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4120) webpack does not respect Es6 import ordering, so the following is not working.

```
   import './A.js';
   import 'B';
```

Help please :-)